# A manhwa about a girl who wants to summon a spirit for her magical academia homework but instead summons a cultivator from another world

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, cultivation

Around 2021–2022, I read this manhwa, and I can't remember the name, and I can't remember the entire plotline, but if anyone knows the name, please help.

It's about a girl who wants to summon a spirit for her magical academy homework but instead summons a cultivator from another world. Her father is an inventor, and her mother left her when she was a baby. She is also a troublemaker since she doesn't have any magical powers, but her father is friends with the principal, so she got in.

I only remember this much, and I hope someone can help me. :D

Comment: Welcome. When you say "a few years ago", how long ago is it exactly (approximately when did you read it)? That can narrow down the time period (i.e. if it's in 2015 for example, then it cannot be stories that came after)

Comment: Reminds me of [The Familiar Of Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Familiar_of_Zero), but that is not a cultivator.

Comment: Hmm... probably not *Her Summon* either, since she's considered a powerful summoner there.